# Redmine can't generate secret token

Tags: ruby, bundle, token, redmine

I have problem with generating secret token.

I'm was trying this:

> [redmine]# rake generate_secret_token rake aborted! LoadError: cannot
>   load such file -- rspec/core
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in
>   `require'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in`
>   block in require'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in
>   `load_dependency'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in`
>   require'
>   /redmine/plugins/easyproject/easy_plugins/easy_extensions/lib/tasks/tests.rake:3:in
>   `<top (required)>'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in`
>   load'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in
>   `block in load'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in`
>   load_dependency'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in
>   `load'
>   /redmine/plugins/easyproject/lib/tasks/easyproject.rake:1:in`
>   block in '
>   /redmine/plugins/easyproject/lib/tasks/easyproject.rake:1:in
>   `each'
>   /redmine/plugins/easyproject/lib/tasks/easyproject.rake:1:in`
>   '
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in
>   `load'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in`
>   block in load'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in
>   `load_dependency'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in`
>   load' /redmine/lib/tasks/redmine.rake:179:in `block
>   in <top (required)>'
>   /redmine/lib/tasks/redmine.rake:179:in`each'
>   /redmine/lib/tasks/redmine.rake:179:in `<top
>   (required)>'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in`
>   load'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in
>   `block in load'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in`
>   load_dependency'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in
>   `load'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/engine.rb:425:in`
>   block in load_tasks'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/engine.rb:425:in
>   `each'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/engine.rb:425:in`
>   load_tasks'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/application.rb:145:in
>   `load_tasks'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in`
>   method_missing' /redmine/Rakefile:7:in `<top
>   (required)>'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in`
>   eval'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in
>   `' (See full trace by running task with --trace)

With adding before "bundle exec" errors are same.

Gem list:

```
> [redmine]# gem list | grep rspec 
rspec (3.1.0) 
rspec-core (3.1.7)
>rspec-expectations (3.1.2) 
rspec-mocks (3.1.3) 
rspec-support (3.1.2)
> [redmine]# gem list | grep core 
core (0.0.6) 
rspec-core (3.1.7)
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: what does your Gemfile look like? has Rspec been added to it?

Comment: Gemfile: http://pastebin.com/a7Hu7N0h it's fresh easyredmine package

Comment: How to integrate RSpec with custom redmine plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is looking for `rspec`. But you don't have it in your Gemfile, which is why `rake` cannot find it (nor bundler).   It appears to be installed, so just add it to your `Gemfile` , then `bundle` and you should be all set.

As it looks like  a rails project, adding this and then running `bundle` should be all set you need.

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0'
end
```

Rails only uses the gems specified in your bundle.

Comment: Thanks! I can't vote up your answer but it's works fine. Have bautiful day!